# Como descobrir quantas vezes um determinado 'level' se repete em uma coluna específica (factor) de um data.frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

Estou trabalhando com 4 data frames (`W`, `X`, `Y` e `Z`) que têm o mesmo número de variáveis. O 'factor' (coluna/variável) 11 foi classificado em 3 'levels' diferentes (1, 2, 3). Eu preciso descobrir quantas vezes cada um desses 'levels' se repetem nessa Coluna 11 em cada um dos data.frames.
Creio que o pacote mais ideal para trabalhar com esse tipo de manipulação de dados seja o dplyr, mas não estou conseguindo montar o código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que a função `table()` pode te ajudar: `table(W$Coluna11)`

Comment: Se precisar só dessa informação recomendo usar o table mesmo. Se quiser a resposta como um data.frame para usar depois (para um gráfico, join ou pra um print melhor) aí o `dplyr` é uma boa opção também. `W %>% count(Coluna11)` seria sua solução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que a função summary funcione para o que você quer.

```r
summary(df$variavel)
```

Como citado no comentário pelo Willian a função table() também resolve o seu problema.

```r
table(df$variavel)
```

Answer (score 2):

Usando apenas R base: coloque os *data.frames* em uma lista e aplique `table` à ela:

```
# Dados de exemplo
set.seed(87365)
W <- data.frame(Coluna1 = LETTERS[1:20],
                Coluna2 = as.factor(sample(1:3, 20, TRUE)))
W -> X -> Y -> Z

dfs <- c("W", "X", "Y", "Z")
# se eles seguem algum padrão, pode usar dfs <- objects(pattern = "padrao")

df.list <- mget(dfs)

> sapply(df.list, function(x) table(x$Coluna2))
  W X Y Z
1 8 8 8 8
2 5 5 5 5
3 7 7 7 7
```

Se todos os data.frames possuem as mesmas variáveis, pode uni-los com uma coluna de identificação e usa-la para agrupamento:

```
dados <- Reduce(rbind, Map(cbind, df.list, df = names(df.list)))
# ou
dados <- dplyr::bind_rows(df.list, .id = "df")
# ou
dados <- data.table::rbindlist(df.list, idcol = "df")

> table(dados$Coluna2, dados$df)
  
    W X Y Z
  1 8 8 8 8
  2 5 5 5 5
  3 7 7 7 7
```